# Redirect after permalink changes

Tags: permalinks, redirect

In old site I had the permalinks like:

```
www.example.com/q-html.html
```

When I change my old site to WordPress 4.0, I set the like:

```
/%postname%/
```

When the URLs come up in a Google search, the user is not redirected to the new URL. Ho w can I set up an automatic redirect?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same probem before, I fixed if by installing [Permalink Finder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-finder/).

If you don't like the result, then you can add Rewrite rules using [WordPress Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Comment: i try this plugin, but its not redirect into orgenal post, its show me error 400

Comment: @RashaSami It works nice for me, did you fix the problem?